# Why is Cron not using local time?

Tags: crontab

```
0 11 * * * $HOME/.aws/killem > cron.log
```

It looks valid to me but it is not running

I've also tried

```
40 11 * * * /home/ec2-user/.aws/killem > cron.log
```

but that doesn't work either

This works:

```
*/5 * * * * date > cron.log
```

I am beginning to think that cron is not picking up the correct time from `/etc/timezone`

I tried specifying as UTC but no joy

```
Local time: Sat 2022-03-19 01:32:00 +07  
Universal time: Fri 2022-03-18 18:32:00 UTC        
RTC time: Fri 2022-03-18 18:32:00
Time zone: Asia/Phnom_Penh (+07+0700)
NTP enabled: yes
```

Comment: You should use an absolute path instead of `$HOME`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314528/why-would-etc-crontab-set-home-in-environment

Comment: That doesn't work either

Comment: The syntax is right, check if `cron` is running with `systemctl status cron`

Comment: Is this a user cronjob or a system one - i.e. would cron be able to execute the script at all?? Do you see something in the system cron.log or system.log showing it tried to do your job ??

Comment: It is running. I wonder if Cron is not getting the datetime from /etc/localtime

Comment: What are the permissions of the directory `/home/ec2-user/.aws/` as well as the file itself `/home/ec2-user/.aws/killem`. What is that `killem`? A Bash script? If so is the first line in that script something like `#!/bin/bash -l`. My guess is the script itself is at fault; perhaps you should post the content of that script in your answer for review?

Comment: If I specify the minute field as */5, the script executes. If i specify an explicit time like 00 12 * * *, it does not execute so I suspect it is probably trying to run it using UTC time instead of the local time I have set

Comment: Could you check your timezone with `timezonectl` then?

Comment: I have solved the problem. No need for you to comment

Comment: I think you mean timedatectl

Comment: Using the $HOME environment variable works just fine @mashuptwice

Answer (score 1):

I found out I need to set the timezone in the crontab:

```
CRON_TZ=Asia/Phnom_Penh
50 13 * * * $HOME/.aws/killem > cron.log
```

Comment: This is not a solution. It is a kludge. Nobody anywhere needs to set the timezone specifically in a crontab unless the server time somehow doesn’t match local time.

Comment: Well, the server time does match the local time. Cron seems to be getting its time from somewhere else but I do not know where

Comment: you need to run `sudo service cron restart` after changing server time

Comment: @LearnProgramming cron is not service.